# How to use callback string to mainform

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method like that written in c#

```
class TorrentDownload
{
    private readonly Thread _getstateThread;        
    public Sohadownload() {
        _getstateThread = new Thread(GetState);
        _getstateThread.Start();            
    }

    TorrentHandle handle=null;
    public void Start(AddTorrentParams param)
    {
        var _session = new Session();            
        if (_session == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sesion");
        _session.ListenOn(6881, 6889);
        handle = _session.AddTorrent(param);                                 
    }

        public void GetState(){
        while (true)
        {
            if (handle == null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                continue;
            }
            var status = handle.GetStatus();
            if (status.IsSeeding)
            {
                break;
            }                
            string _state = status.State.ToString();
            double _up = status.UploadRate;
            double _down = status.DownloadRate;
            double _process = status.Progress;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //Console.WriteLine("State {0} Process {1}", _state, _process);            
       }
    }        
}
```

now in `Main()` program I just want to call value in `_state`, `_up`, `_dơn`, `_process` variable to show in Console.Writeline
I am trying use delegate but it's not working.

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: This looks like polling. You have to be more specific and explicit. What exactly does not work? What is the delegate call? Can't see any delegates in your post, use proper tags: winforms, threading, etc ...

Comment: thanks you for help. Im try using delegate and it done.

Answer (score 2):

based on your requirements, here an idea

construct a class that will manage the status and make public properties in order to enable you to access the variables values

and from your main function you can call the `GetState` and then you can access the values of `_state`, `_up`, `_down`, `_process`

you can make your properties and method and also the class as `static` if you want, but here the sample code:

```
public class ManageStatus
{
    private string _state;
    private double _up,_down,_process;

    public string State
    {
        get{ return _state;}
        set{ _state=value;}
    }
    public string State
    {
        get{ return _state;}
        set{ _state=value;}
    }
    public double Up
    {
        get{ return _up;}
        set{ _up=value;}
    }
    public double Down
    {
        get{ return _down;}
        set{ _down=value;}
    }
    public double Process
    {
        get{ return _process;}
        set{ _process=value;}
    }
    public void GetState()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (handle == null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                continue;
            }
            var status = handle.GetStatus();
            if (status.IsSeeding)
            {
                break;
            }                
            _state = status.State.ToString();
            _up = status.UploadRate;
            _down = status.DownloadRate;
            _process = status.Progress;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
         }  
    }
}
```

and in your main code you can do this

```
public static void Main()
{
     var status=new ManageStatus();
     status.GetState();
     Console.Writline("State:{0}",status.State);
     Console.Writline("Up:{0}",status.Up);
     Console.Writline("Down:{0}",status.Down);
     Console.Writline("Process:{0}",status.Process);
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: thanks for help me, I try your method and sample code. but i not working.In Main program consoleWriteLine not print any thing

Comment: I try your method without WHILE LOOP and it working fine. but my program need run in WHILE LOOP to get data download, so how can do this to fix problem

Answer (score 2):

You could print the line inside `GetState()` instead of `Main`:

```
public void GetState() 
{ 
    while (true)
    {

        if (handle == null)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            continue;
        }

        var status = handle.GetStatus();

        if (status.IsSeeding)
        {
            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("State: {0}, Up: {1}, Down: {2}, Process: {3}",
                          status.State.ToString(),
                          status.UploadRate,
                          status.DownloadRate,
                          status.Progress);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }  
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. My purpose that is want use the value of variable in while  loop for another methoad that show in commanline

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to my other answer, you could modift `GetState` and move the loop to `Main`:

```
// N.B: I don't know where you get handle from,
//      I'll just adapt the code you've posted for simplicity
public WhateverTypeStatusIs GetState()
{
    if (handle == null)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        continue;
    }
    var status = handle.GetStatus();
    if (status.IsSeeding)
    {
        break;
    }                

    return status;
}

public static void Main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var status = GetState();

        if (status.IsSeeding)
        {
            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("State: {0}, Up: {1}, Down: {2}, Process: {3}",
                          status.State.ToString(),
                          status.UploadRate,
                          status.DownloadRate,
                          status.Progress);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Of course this `Main` doesn't do much and is blocked untile `GetState()` returns, but given that we don't know more about your program, I think it serves as a decent example.

I'm also assuming that `handle.GetStatus()` doesn't return `null`.

Comment: thanks you alot. that is full my code. . if I put conssol.WriteLine in While Loop, it done. But i want how to other Method or function that can use the value of variable in While Loop any time